# Why would HTML::fragment not work but ::XML work?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have been trying to run some processing on some HTML fragments, in doing so with Nokogiri I ran into an issue I can't seem to understand.

I am using this code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment xml

doc.search("//text()[contains(.,'#{@wordbefore}')]").each do |node|
  node.replace(node.content.gsub(/#{@wordbefore}/, ''))
end
```

With that code, the entire block is skipped. Yet, if I use:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML xml
```

it does work. I've been trying to sort out why this is and can't. Since I'm really passing code fragments, and I don't really want inner elements to be encoded, or the XML namespace on every fragment I really would love to keep this as the HTML::fragment. But can't determine if this is a bug I've run into or just something I'm doing wrong.

Update: 
Here is the entire thing I setup in my scratch to do testing. One other note. I realize this will kill what's in the term element. In reality that part isn't there when this is run as it changed at a different stage, but this was the easiest way for me to grab real content.

```
xml = <<-EOXML
<p dir="ltr" class="FM_Body">The Cortex-A5 MPCore processor is a high-performance, low-power, ARM macrocell with an L1 cache subsystem that provides full virtual memory capabilities. Up to four individual cores can be linked in a cache-coherent cluster, under the control of a <term>Snoop Control Unit</term> (SCU), that maintains L1 data cache coherency for memory marked as shared. The Cortex-A5 MPCore processor implements the ARMv7 architecture and runs 32-bit ARM instructions, 16-bit and 32-bit Thumb instructions, and 8-bit Java<tm tmtype="tm">Java</tm> bytecodes in Jazelle state.</p>
EOXML

doc = Nokogiri::XML xml
@wordbefore = "Java"

doc.search("//text()[contains(.,'#{@wordbefore}')]").each do |node|
 node.replace(node.content.gsub(/#{@wordbefore}/, ''))
end

p doc.to_xml
```

Comment: Can we see that `xml`?

Answer (score 0):

The folks who maintain Nokogiri got back to me. Turns out this is a known issue with HTML fragments and Xpath searching. In my particular case the solution is to go up the tree via `.//text()` instead of just `//text()`.